# Groovy == operator

Tags: groovy

Until now, my understanding was that `==` is an operator overload for `.equals()`. However, I recently discovered that

```
new Integer(1) == new Long(1) // returns true
```

whereas

```
new Integer(1).equals(new Long(1)) // returns false
```

so I guess `==` is not exactly a shorthand for `.equals()`, so how does it determine equality?

Comment: This continues to bite me when using GORM, which has Long database IDs. Requests from JSON generated integer values yielding behavior like:
groovy:000> m = [1L : 'foo']
===> [1:foo]
groovy:000> m.containsKey(1L)
===> true
groovy:000> m.containsKey(1)
===> false

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`==` in Groovy is roughly equivalent to `equals()`, however, you'll find it's different from Java when comparing different classes with the same value - if the class is `Comparable`. Groovy also does type casting if possible.

If you check out the code, it looks like ultimately [`compareToWithEqualityCheck()`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation.java#L557) is executed for `==`.

Answer (score 10):

It turns out `==` does not delegate to `equals()`, it delegates to `compareTo`. So `==` will return true if `a.compareTo(b)` returns 0

So in this particular case

```
new Integer(1).compareTo(new Long(1)) == 0
```

so therefore:

```
new Integer(1) == new Long(1)
```

but this does not necessarily mean that

```
new Integer(1).equals(new Long(1))
```

The reason why this is all so weird and confusing is because the [contract of Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) does not require that it is consistent with equals, though it is strongly recommended.

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals. This is so because sorted sets (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is inconsistent with equals.