# How to override equals when extending LinkedHashMap in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

According to the documentation the `==` operator calls the equals method. This doesn't seem to be the case with maps in groovy. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

When a class extends LinkedHashMap and overrides equals

```
class CustomExtend extends LinkedHashMap<String, String> {
    @Override
    boolean equals(Object o) {
        false
    }
}

def customExtend = new CustomExtend()
customExtend.put('key', 'value')

assert [key:'value'] == customExtend
assert customExtend == [key:'value']//should be false
```

Another strategy I tried is delegation

```
class CustomDelegate {
    @Delegate
    LinkedHashMap map = [:]
    @Override
    boolean equals(Object o) {
        false
    }
}

def customDelegate = new CustomDelegate()
customDelegate.put('key', 'value')

assert [key:'value'] == customDelegate
assert customDelegate == [key:'value']//should be false
```

Comment: Groovy equality checks are ... idiosyncratic.  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687154/groovy-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I don't think it is a bug (may be debatable), but it is behavior that might not be obvious.

Because Groovy's dynamic dispatch dispatches on runtime type, your `equals(Object)` isn't be invoked because Groovy provides a custom `equals(Map)` method for `Map` instances and that will win over `equals(Object)`.  One way to cause your assertion to behave the way you expect is to provide an `equals(Map)` method.

```
class CustomDelegate {
    @Delegate
    LinkedHashMap map = [:]

    boolean equals(Map o) {
        false
    }

    static void main(args) {
        def customDelegate = new CustomDelegate()
        customDelegate.put('key', 'value')

        // both of these will pass...
        assert [key: 'value'] == customDelegate
        assert customDelegate != [key: 'value']
    }
}
```

There are reasons you may not really want to do that, but I hope that addresses your question.

Comment: Thanks! that explains it. I knew there were added methods I wasn't aware there was one for equals added. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#equals(java.util.Map)

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#equals(java.util.Map) is the method at issue here.

Comment: The implementation is at https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/01309f9d4be34ddf93c4a9943b5a97843bff6181/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L11610-L11632.